# Using Eclipse for androidSDK, when I go to run, I get WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am completely new to Java, and Android, and eclipse. When doing the initial Hello, Android tutorial, I go to run and get the following:

```
WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
```

Answer (score 15):

Goto DDMS perspective, click on the down arrow next to the screen capture camera icon and select reset adb from the dropdown menu.

My apk file was not deploying either, resetting adb sorted it out. :)

Comment: I could not see screen capture camera icon on DDMS perspective.

Comment: If you cannot see that icon it might be because you don't have the emulator running at the time - Eclipse has to be connected to the emulator for that perspective to be useful!

Answer (score 12):

Even easier fix:
In Windows open command prompt (cmd.exe).
In Linux open Terminal.
Locate `adb.exe` in SDK folder ..`\android-sdk\platform-tools\abd.exe`

```
cd <sdk directory> (move to the folder listed above)
dir (to make sure abd.exe is in that directory)
adb kill-server (stop the abd service, won't return anything)
adb start-server (start the abd service back up, should give a couple of readings)
```

Then retest, problem solved!

Comment: @Gili I am getting similar problem, when i do start0server i get following message. * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon *

Comment: daemon started successfully - but no change. Still "partition already in use".

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem, that's why I found myself here.

**What I did is to run cmd then adb kill-server, then open task manager in windows and kill the emulator-x86.exe process.
Then re-run the project, it should work fine.**

I guess adb kill-server isn't even necessary.

Comment: killing preocess did not help in my case.

Comment: @Pritesh Did you find an other way then ?

Answer (score 2):

If you consider this tutorial about "[Read/Write Android Emulator sdcard.img in Windows](http://deltafalcon.com/2010/04/mounting-an-android-emulator-sd-card-image-in-windows/)", check that this virtual disk isn't somehow already mounted:

[image: mounting image disk]

> If ImDisk complains of the file being in use, close the emulator.
>   They won’t run together.
>   Unmounting the image in Android does not allow the image to be mounted in Windows, the emulator must be shut down in order to free the image from its locked state

The [OP JiminyCricket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866723/) confirms it was some kind of "resource lock":

> Simple restart of my OS fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Simple restart of my OS fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Delete that AVD and create a new one. That worked for me, and it's the simplest way, with no configuration at all.

Comment: Worked for me too. Note: created from eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Just Restart Your Android SDK and Eclipse
If it not works even restarting PC
just delete that Android virtual device and create new one using AVD.

Hope It Helps !!

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this is to simply clean your projects.    From the menu  PROJECT>CLEAN...Clean All projects.

This worked for me when rebooting eclipse did not.

I take it back... this was temporary and incomplete.   Even rebooting my eclipse and my system did not help until I killed the adb service, restarted it per the suggestions here.  Now everything seems clean (knock on wood)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that no proxy software is preventing Eclipse from connecting to the internet.

My problem was solved by doing this!

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to simply create a new virtual Android device in the Eclipse -> Window -> AVD Manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete pid file from all blow directories
.android\avd\[your_device].avd\cache.img.lock &
hardware-qemu.ini.lock &
sdcard.img.lock &
userdata-qemu.img.lock directories

Then start AVD.
```

Answer (score 0):

Go the AVD Manager then select the device and go to edit button
and make sure RAM is not go beyond 768M in the memory options. 
Sometimes windows may fail to emulate, try progressively smaller value first 
if the emulator fails to launch.