# Eclipse fire up new Android instance every time you clicks "Run"

Tags: android, android-emulator, installation

One of my computer has the issue with eclipse and android SDK.

Every time I clicks "Run" or "Debug", then the eclipse will open up a new android instance instead of refresh the app in the "opened" one.

In the meantime, the console prints

```
    [2011-09-02 16:46:13 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. 
Changes will not persist!
    [2011-09-02 16:46:13 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. 
Changes will not persist!
```

I have restarted my computer and the problem still there.

P.S.  I have never get android properly working on this computer, but I have set another three laptops working well. They are all windows7 64bit machines.

Thank you.

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854262/using-eclipse-for-androidsdk-when-i-go-to-run-i-get-warning-data-partition-alr

Comment: I have tried that solution, and it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I hate that you did all of that work, even re-installing the OS - the answer is fairly simple. If it ever happens again (and it will, I deal with it often), you need to kill the adb via command-line, close the emulator, close eclipse, restart eclipse, then edit the Run Configurations. Choose the config you use, click the Target tab and toggle the "Wipe User Data" checkbox to on. Then click apply and Run. Then just toggle it back off and apply. You're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error-message. What helped me is typing the command `adb kill-server` and then restarting Eclipse. Try it!

Comment: Well, nothing can fix my issue. I've ended by re installing my OS, and  finally get it fixed.