# Android:Simulator instance newly opens every time

Tags: android

I have been trying to search about this issue in the forums etc. but have not found any solutions yet. I have installed Eclipse 3.7.1 and using Android 3.0. When i want to debug the Android project, i select Debug As->Android application, simulator opens after a few mins but doesn't launch my app even after did lock swipe, but app is being installed. But, my biggest problem is, every time when i select Debug As->Android application, it always opens new simulator instance instead of launching my app in the existing launched simulator. Its killing, i'm not able to Debug my app at all directly.
Could someone please help me to set it properly?

Thank you!

CONSOLE: (every time when launches the new simulator)

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing com.company.myproject.SplashScreenActivity activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'avd3.2' is not available. Launching new emulator.
Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd3.2'
2012-02-12 13:45:13.478 emulator-arm[2522:80b] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Connection refused
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the console log in the question. Please check that and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused for the sensor ports is a common problem when using a 64-bit install of Eclipse. Sometimes this error happens to working setups sporadically, but because this is a constant problem I am guessing that it is because you are running 64-bit Eclipse.

Developing in the 32-bit version of Eclipse should fix it.

Comment: Do i need to install 32 bit v. Eclipse now? I'm developing on mac. Can installation be overwritten or need to install this freshly?

Comment: Install fresh. You can still keep your projects.

Comment: I Tried your suggestion(installed eclipse 32 bit on mac), but i'm continuously observing the same issue.

Comment: I guess, adb kill-server resolved my issue. The following link helped on this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280181/eclipse-fire-up-new-android-instance-every-time-you-clicks-run