# Why Emulator was re create automatically at Every time

Tags: java, android

When I first run my application it works well, however the second time it is run a new emulator is created automatically I think and this causes an error.

I Used Windows7 64bit, Eclipse Juno

My Error Is:

```
WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\STS-040\.android\avd\android.avd/sdcard.img
WARNING: Cache partition already in use.Changes will not persist!
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer. emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the emulator

In ecpilse window click

**Navigate** in the top bar then **Run Configuration**

a new window will pop up

click the **target** tab here and select (**check**) your AVD manager

Hit the the run button !!

It'll work like a charm ;-)

Comment: Already i did tat...but noe also having same erro..

Comment: see if this helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854262/using-eclipse-for-androidsdk-when-i-go-to-run-i-get-warning-data-partition-al

Comment: 1.run->cmd->Your Sdk Location->adb kill-server (stop the abd service, won't return anything),
2.run->cmd->Your Sdk Location->adb start-server (start the abd service back up, should give a couple of readings)..

Comment: if you find the answer correct please 1). Click the tick to accept it as wrtie answer 2). Vote up :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even i face somewhat the same problem. Restarting eclipse or sometimes restarting the computer itself is required to solve it.

I would suggest you to check whether the emulator is getting detected in eclipse by selecting the DDMS perspective and checking the devices. In case the device is not detected you need not wait for the emulator to boot and waste your time as the program from eclipse won't run in it.