# android app not installing, eclipse juno

Tags: android

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.
I created my first android application project, and it's supposed to display the Hello World message, but I run it and get nothing(well, the emulator starts but then nothing), no console output view, no error.If I run it again the console appears(...WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!) and the emulator opens in new window but again nothing
Please tell me what's wrong and how to install and run the app?
after first run(pic1&2), after second run (pic3)
[image: first run]

[image: emulator]

[image: second run]

Comment: Well, I restarted Eclipse, and ran the app again and left it. After an hour or so I finally did get the Hello World message on the emulator screen, and the app is among those "installed" on the emulator, so I guess it was working correctly before, but what's with an hour wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the emulator is already running and you are launching a new instance of it... based on the log it has been launched earlier and perhaps it hasn't shut down properly.

-Restart adb as poitroae suggested in an earlier answer.

-If that doesn't help, restart Eclipse.

-If that doesn't help, restart your computer.

If you're still having issues after that, post back.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset/Restart the adb server**. You should do that over the command line. Make sure that you are in your `/android-sdk-root/platform-tools` directory.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: when I try to run it there is the "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @KatrinnaL I added some info.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app, you will see the .apk file under the "bin" folder.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I thought he wants to install the app? I supposed he wants to install on an Android phone?

Comment: I agree with Karan. Try cleaning your project. It usually works for me after I clean the project...

Answer (score 0):

wait! As far as i can make out, you're just launching the emulator. Isn't it? there's a green button at the top. (like a "play" button) just press it.

Or right click on the project you want to run, and click on "run as > android application" and watch the emulator play your app.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean your project from project-> clean and also donot forget to wipe user data on android emulator...
here is some good discussion about your problem...

[Using Eclipse for androidSDK, when I go to run, I get WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854262/using-eclipse-for-androidsdk-when-i-go-to-run-i-get-warning-data-partition-al)